# How to find the min dates from the list of items?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table structure like this

```
id  |  itemId |  date |
1   |  a1     | 6/14/2015
2   |  a1     | 3/14/2015
3   |  a1     | 2/14/2015
4   |  b1     | 6/14/2015
5   |  c1     | 6/14/2015
```

From this table structure I am trying to get all the distinct items that has min date. for e.g. I am trying to get id = 3,4 and 5.

I have tried following code but I couldn't

```
var items = (from i in _db.Items
             //where min(i.date) // doesn't seem right
             group i by i.itemID
             into d select new
             {
                 iId = d.Key,
             }).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample data, I would do this:

```
var query =
    from i in _db.Items
    group i by i.itemId into gis
    let lookup = gis.ToLookup(x => x.date, x => x.id)
    from x in lookup[gis.Min(y => y.date)]
    select x;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. How can I return Id also?

Answer (score -1):

```
var items = from i in _db.Items
            group i.date by i.itemID
            into d select new {
                iId = d.Key, iDate = d.Min()
            };
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted. This may well be the cause of a downvote, although I have no way to be sure.)